# Is there a way to use JSON to add an internal comment within Jira?

Tags: json, automation, jira

I am working on my company's Jira Service Desk project and we are having some trouble with some of our workflow automation. Currently to move an issue through the workflow from Step 1 (Waiting for support) -> Step 2 (In Progress) a comment is required to be entered by the user after clicking on the "In Progress" button to successfully move the issue to the next step.

This is working as intended but we wanted to utilize an automation rule as well that will automatically transition the issues from Step 1 to Step 2 if a comment added to an issue. The problem occurs due to the workflow validator requiring that a comment be added during the transition for the issue to move to the next status.

The good thing is that our automation plugin (Automation for Jira) does allow you to add JSON configurations to the steps within the rule. For example, I am able to add the JSON to add a comment to the rule during the transition, which is exactly what we want. But the problem here is that the comment is an external comment that is sent to the customer. We would need this comment to be an internal comment so the customer is not sent any unnecessary information when we already have users reaching out to them.

What we are trying to achieve is to have an issue in the “Waiting for Support” status, then when an internal user comments on that issue it is transitioned automatically to the next status (In Progress) using the automation rule. But due to our workflow requirements we are also needing to add an additional internal comment during that transition for the transition to be valid. Our workflow requires us to add a comment during the transition from one status to another before it will allow the status to be changed.

So far I have tried a few different things with the JSON code but I am not familiar at all with JSON and have not been able to get it figured out in how to differentiate between a public/external comment and a private/internal comment. I have gotten it to where the comment is added during the transition and then the automation runs successfully, but the problem is this comment becomes an external comment when we would need it to be internal and visible to only our service desk users.

```
   {
        "update": {

        "comment": [
    {
        "add": {
        "body": "Issue issue.key has been transitioned to the In Progress 
        status per automation guidelines."

    }

    }
    ]
    }
    }



This is the JSON code that is added at the status transition step that works. Just not 100% the right way. I am trying to somehow figure out a way to have the comment that is added be internal as opposed to external.
```

I was able to use the "Comment on issue" action and mimic my rule plus the additional internal comment with the "comment on issue" action. After exporting the JSON this is what I got:

I was able to create my rule with the "comment on issue" action and leave it as an internal comment. After that I exported the JSON to see what it looked like and this is what I got:

```
    "cloud":true,
"rules":[
{
"id":188601,
"clientKey":"jira:12205936",
"name":"Incident Comment Transition ",
"state":"ENABLED",
"description":null,
"canOtherRuleTrigger":false,
"notifyOnError":"FIRSTERROR",
"authorAccountId":"5a328efd101d3439bb11039c",
"actorAccountId":"557058:f58131cb-b67d-43c7-b30d-6b58d40bd077",
"created":1559219471531,
"updated":1559221244585,
"trigger":{
"id":"3628751",
"component":"TRIGGER",
"parentId":null,
"conditionParentId":null,
"schemaVersion":1,
"type":"jira.issue.event.trigger:commented",
"value":{
"synchronous":false,
"eventKey":"jira:issue_updated",
"issueEvent":"issue_commented"
},
"children":[
],
"conditions":[
]
},
"components":[
{
"id":"3628752",
"component":"CONDITION",
"parentId":null,
"conditionParentId":null,
"schemaVersion":1,
"type":"jira.jql.condition",
"value":"assignee != empty and resolution = unresolved and status = \"waiting for support\" and issuetype=\"incident\"",
"children":[
],
"conditions":[
]
},
{
"id":"3628753",
"component":"ACTION",
"parentId":null,
"conditionParentId":null,
"schemaVersion":6,
"type":"jira.issue.transition",
"value":{
"operations":[
],
"advancedFields":"",
"sendNotifications":true,
"useLegacyRendering":false,
"transitionMode":"status",
"destinationStatus":{
"type":"ID",
"value":"3"
},
"transitionMatch":"",
"transition":null,
"ignoreConditions":false
},
"children":[
],
"conditions":[
]
},
{
"id":"3628754",
"component":"ACTION",
"parentId":null,
"conditionParentId":null,
"schemaVersion":1,
"type":"jira.issue.comment",
"value":{
"comment":"Issue {{issue.key}} has been moved to the In Progress status per automation guidelines.",
"publicComment":false,
"commentVisibility":null,
"sendNotifications":true,
"addCommentOnce":true,
"useLegacyRendering":false
},
"children":[
],
"conditions":[
]
}
],
"projects":[
{
"projectId":"10610",
"projectTypeKey":"service_desk"
}
],
"labels":[
]
}
    ]
```

Would you be able to tell me which part of this is the section that will add the internal comment? I was thinking maybe if I could just use that JSON in the "transition issue" step of the rule this may accomplish what I am trying to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it with JSON, but you should be able to do it within their GUI.

Within the `Comment on issue` action, Under `More options -> Service Desk` you should see a check box for `Share with customer`.

[Ref : Rule Playground](https://docs.automationforjira.com/rule-playground/#/rule/115366/1748273)

You can just create a dummy rule and [export](https://docs.automationforjira.com/upgrade/import-export.html) the rule to get the JSON.

PS : Their [support](https://codebarrel.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/1) is supposed to be very good as well.

Comment: Hi John,

I have already looked into that "Comment on issue" action and the problem here is that the action will occur after the transition step in the workflow. So this wouldn't meet the workflow requirement and still would leave the issue stuck in the first status.

I was hoping there may be a way to have two things execute at the same time within the automation, such as have the transition and comment on issue action happen simultaneously but haven't quite been able to figure that out yet.

Comment: Hi John, see my edit above please regarding the rule creation and JSON export!

Comment: `publicComment : false` seems to be the relevant line, try adding that in parallel to the "body" key.

Comment: Thanks for the help John. After doing some research it appears that it is not possible with the current API limitations from Atlassian to perform an internal comment at the same time as a workflow transition.

Here are some issues regarding this bug: https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/JSDECO-71

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSDSERVER-5034